# Map JSON to C# Class when attribute names have spaces and reserved words

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization, restsharp

I am consuming a REST API service. In the service response JSON, there are attribute names that include spaces and reserved words. I'm trying to map it to a C# class, but I can't assign attribute names that are the same as the field names.

Currently, the mapping only succeeds when the JSON attribute and C# class name of a field matches exactly, otherwise the value comes in as `null`.

Below is the JSON returned from the service:

```json
{
   "value": [   {
      "accountNo": "JKBXXXXXXXXXVNX1",
      "mainSalesPerson": "XXXXX",
      "accountName": "XXXXXX",
      "ledgerBalance": "-2,298.70",
      "T+3": "0.00",
      "T+4": "0.00",
      "T+5 and Above": "2,298.70",
      "riskRatedPortfolioValue": "109,057.50",
      "exposure": "106,758.80",
      "costToFirm": "",
      "incomeToFirm": "14.59",
      "costToIncome(%)": "",
      "exposure(%)": "2.11",
      "O/S Balance": "-2,298.70"
   }],
   "success": true
}
```

I have used the following mapping class:

```csharp
public class CountObject
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string success { get; set; }
}

public class RiskManagementQueryValueObject
{
    public string accountNo { get; set; }
    public string mainSalesPerson { get; set; }
    public string accountName { get; set; }
    public string ledgerBalance { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "T+3")]
    public string T3 { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "T+4")]
    public string T4 { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "T+5 and Above")]
    public string T5_and_Above { get; set; }
    public string riskRatedPortfolioValue { get; set; }
    public string exposure { get; set; }
    public string costToFirm { get; set; }
    public string incomeToFirm { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "costToIncome(%)")]
    public string costToIncome { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "exposure(%)")]
    public string exposure_per { get; set; }

    [SerializeAs(Name = "O/S Balance")]
    public string OS_Balance { get; set; }
}

public class RiskManagementQueryHeadertObject
{
    public List<RiskManagementQueryValueObject> value { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
}
```

And this how I talk to the service:

```csharp
public List<RiskManagementQueryValueObject> getOverdues()
{
    List<RiskManagementQueryValueObject> overdues = new List<RiskManagementQueryValueObject>();
    var count = 0.0;

    try
    {
        var restProxy = new RESTProxy();
        var request = restProxy.initRestRequest("/cam/riskmanagement/1/query/count", Method.POST, new { requestCriteriaMap = new { currency = "LKR" } });
        CountObject data = restProxy.Execute<CountObject>(request);

        if (data.success.ToString().ToLower() != "true")
            return null;

        //get the page count
        var pageCount = Math.Truncate(count / 300) + 1;

        for (int j = 0; j < pageCount; j++)
        {
            var request2 = restProxy.initRestRequest(string.Format("/cam/riskmanagement/1/query/{0}", (j + 1).ToString()), Method.POST, new { requestCriteriaMap = new { currency = "LKR" } });
            RiskManagementQueryHeadertObject data2 = restProxy.Execute<RiskManagementQueryHeadertObject>(request2);

            overdues.AddRange(data2.value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        overdues = null;
    }

    return overdues;
}
```

```csharp
public class RESTProxy
{
    string DEFAULT_HOST = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/";
    string DEFAULT_MODULE = "xxx-rest";
    string DEFAULT_USER = "xxx:xxx:xxx";
    string DEFAULT_PASS = "xxx";

    public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(string.Concat(DEFAULT_HOST, DEFAULT_MODULE))
        {
            Authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator(DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASS, DEFAULT_HOST)
        };

        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            throw response.ErrorException;
        }
        return response.Data;
    }

    public RestRequest initRestRequest(string pRestResourceName, Method pRestServiceVerb, object pRestRequestBody)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(pRestResourceName, pRestServiceVerb);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;


        if (pRestRequestBody != null)
        {
            request.AddBody(pRestRequestBody);
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this and serialize all the fields into my class definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. I added `[DeserializeAs(Name ="")]` instead of `[SerializeAs(Name ="")]`. I just did this in my C# Map class:

```
public class RiskManagementQueryValueObject
    {
        public string accountNo { get; set; }
        public string mainSalesPerson { get; set; }
        public string accountName { get; set; }
        public string ledgerBalance { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "T+3")]
        public string T3 { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "T+4")]
        public string T4 { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "T+5 and Above")]
        public string T5_and_Above { get; set; }
        public string riskRatedPortfolioValue { get; set; }
        public string exposure { get; set; }
        public string costToFirm { get; set; }
        public string incomeToFirm { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "costToIncome(%)")]
        public string costToIncome { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "exposure(%)")]
        public string exposure_per { get; set; }

        [DeserializeAs(Name = "O/S Balance")]
        public string OS_Balance { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What namespace is DeserializeAs in? I cant find it?

Comment: @jeffkenn it is `RestSharp.Deserializers` namespace

Answer (score 10):

Using the JsonProperty attribute worked for me:

**Example:**

This C# class:

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name/ + 1")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

maps to the following javascript object:

```
var input = {"Name/ + 1": "PostName"};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But at this point `RiskManagementQueryHeadertObject data2 = restProxy.Execute<RiskManagementQueryHeadertObject>(request2);` it does not map to the correct property/attribute name. I am still getting the value as `null`

Comment: This property worked wonderfully! Just a reminder, you need to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace in any reference to `JsonProperty` for this to work.