# Couldn't Map JSON Payload having Attribute Name with Space and Reserve words to C# Class in RestSharp Ver. 108

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

6 years back I wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391324/map-json-to-c-sharp-class-with-attribute-names-having-space-and-reserve-words) for RestSharp version older than 108.

But now with RestSharp Version 108 I am unable to use the same as I am getting an error as

> Could not load type 'RestSharp.Deserializers.DeserializeAsAttribute'
> from assembly 'RestSharp, Version=108.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75'.

My JSON Payload is as:

```
{
    "agentType": "Sub Broker",
    "agentCode": "FWM",
    "agentName": "FWM",
    "default": "Y"
}
```

In my c# Class I have this; Note that default is a reserved word, hence I made it as "IsDefault" mapped to the correct attribute name using `DeserializeAsAttribute` from RestSharp Version prior to 108:

```
public class AgentInformation
    {
        public string agentType { get; set; }
        public string agentCode { get; set; }
        public string agentName { get; set; }
        [DeserializeAs(Name = "default")]
        public string isDefault { get; set; }
    }
```

I am calling the API from RestSharp Version 108 as:

```
try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://xxxx.io/v3/xxxxxxx");
                var request = new RestRequest();
                request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; }; 
                var response = client.Get<AgentInformation>(request);
                var data = response;
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {

                throw er;
            }
```

**Update:**

As @jhambright suggested in his comment, I used `System.Text.Json` in the following way and it worked.

Note here, `System.Text.Json` offers `JsonPropertyName`

```
public class AgentInformation
    {
        public string agentType { get; set; }
        public string agentCode { get; set; }
        public string agentName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("default")]
        public string isDefault { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in my code I did the following way:

```
try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("https://xxx.xxx.io/v3/xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx");
                //client.AddDefaultHeader("application/json", () => new RestSharp.Serializers.Newtonsoft.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());
                var request = new RestRequest();
                request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; }; 
                var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
                var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
                var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model.AgentInformation>(response.Content, options);

                Console.WriteLine(data.agentInformation.isDefault);
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {

                throw er;
            }
```

This [resource](https://code-maze.com/introduction-system-text-json-examples/) here also helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I believe RestSharp is now using `System.Text.Json` for default json deserialization. You should be able to use `[JsonPropertyName("default")]` attribute to direct the deserializer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: Thank you for your insights. But I believe, we need to get the `Response.Content` then deserialize using `NewtonSoft.JSON` library instead of `System.Text.JSON`

Comment: You can still configure RestSharp to use Newtonsoft with the `RestSharp.Newtonsoft.Json` package (it is however not maintained anymore. [RESTSharp serialization documentation](https://restsharp.dev/serialization.html)

You can also use request.Get and then manually use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` to deserialize the `response.content` value.

Comment: I think there is a correction to be made. Instead of `[PropertyName("default")]` one should use `[JsonPropertyName("default")]` Documentation here: [JsonPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-6.0)